# C# how can i reset the position of labels?

Tags: c#, .net

so i have this set up to store the horizontal values:

```
foreach (Label waitingCar in labels)
{
    int i = 0;

    carVal[i,0] = i + 1;
    int x = waitingCar.Left;  
    carVal[i, 0] = x;

    int y = waitingCar.Top;   
    carVal[i, 1] = y;
}
```

Then i have this to reset the positions but it seems to reset them all to the same positions which seems to be 1,0 or something (the top left of the form) clearly the values either aren't being stored correctly or being read correctly.

```
for (int i = 0; i <carVal.GetLength(0); i++)
{ 
  waitingCar.Location = new Point(carVal[i,0],carVal[i,1]);     
}
```

For a bit of extra information my labels are waitingCar and waitingCar1 to 9.

Comment: What is the line `carVal[i,0] = i + 1;` for? also, i don't see you update `i` anywhere in the storing loop so you will only ever write to `carVal[0,0]` and `carVal[0,1]`. Lastly, in your 2nd code block why loop over `j` at all, you are just using the hardcoded values `0` and `1` anyway.

Comment: I was hoping that `i + 1` would mean that for ever time it loops to do a new label it would change the position its storing it to `[1,0]` then `[2,0]` etc.As for looping over `j` you have a very good point ill fix that bit but still not sure how to do what i want with storing the values in the loop.

Comment: `i = i +1` would do that, `carVal[i,0] = i + 1;` just sets `carVal[0,0]` to the value 1. However that being said, instead of doing `var carVal = new int[labels.Length,2];` you might find it easier to do `var carVal = new List<Point>();` Then your foreach code just becomes `{ carVal.Add(waitingCar.Location); }` and the for code becomes `{ waitingCar.Location = carVal[i]; }`

Comment: I'll try this out in a bit but i was wondering how does this deal with the horizontal ? or does `waitingCar.Location` return both vertical and horizontal values ?

Comment: You need to debug it. This is a great time to learn how to use a debugger. Go grab a book or tutorial.

Comment: `foreach (Label waitingCar in labels)  {     int i = 0; ` so you always start at 0 for each label?? Shouldn't it be out of the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**
As **@TaW** said, the problem is that you are setting `int i = 0;` every time inside the `foreach` loop every time. It should be set outside the `foreach` loop and incremented within the loop. And as **@Scott Chamberlain** said, The code only ever sets the first `carVal` item and by default, since `carVal` is of Type `int[,]`, the default values with be `0` for each item, even though you don't set them.

Though I don't have VS now to confirm.

**Solution 1:** If you wanted keep using the `int`2D array, though I would suggest a `List<Point>` as **@Scott Chamberlain** suggested, you could use something like this. I don't have visual studio right now so my syntax could be wrong:

```
var carVal = int[labels.length,2];
foreach(var waitingCar in labels.Select( (lbl,i) > new { lbl = lbl, i = i } ){
    carVal[waitingCar.i,0] = waitingCar.lbl.Left;
    carVal[waitingCar.i,1] = waitingCar.lbl.Top;
}
```

then to reset you would using the following. If course this assumes that `(labels.Length == carVal.GetLength(0))`

```
foreach(var waitingCar in labels.Select( (lbl,i) > new { lbl = lbl, i = i } ){
    waitingCar.lbl.Location = new Point(carVal[waitingCar.i,0],carVal[waitingCar.i,1]);
}
```

**Solution 2:** If you wanted to use a `List<Point>` instead, as per **@Scott Chamberlain** suggestion, then consider this option:

```
var carVal = new List<Point>();
foreach(var waitingCar in labels){
    carVal.Add(waitingCar.Location);
}
```

Then to reset, If course this assumes that `(labels.Length == carVal.Count)`. I'm assuming that `labels` is of type `Label[]` (array) and I've set `carVal` of type `List<Point>` (list).

```
for(int i = 0; i < carVal.Count; i++){
    labels[i].Location = carVal[i];
}
```

*Again I don't have visual studio with me so I may have gotten some syntax wrong*